# can't send data through l2cap raw socket for local controller - [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, bluetooth, raw-sockets, l2cap

I tried to connect to my local bluetooth controller through l2cap layer in order to see which services I am supporting by using SDP protocol.
**don't want to use sdptool

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.BTPROTO_L2CAP) as l2cap_sock:
      l2cap_sock.bind((local_bd_addr,0))
      l2cap_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
      l2cap_sock.send(b'SDP PAYLOAD')
```

ERROR Result:

```
[Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

any ideas,
thanks